# downloader.DownloadFileTaskAsync stuck after downloading the first file

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using [downloader](https://github.com/bezzad/Downloader)

My code is

```
    public DownloadWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartDownloading();
    }

    private async void StartDownloading()
    {
            var downloader = new DownloadService(downloadOpt);
            downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChanged;

            await downloader.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url1, file1);
            await downloader.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url2, file2);
    }

    private void OnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, Downloader.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
             this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {

             downloadProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            
            }));
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

The first file is downloaded and it gets stuck at the second file.

If I comment out the first download, the second file is downloaded just fine.

Creating another downloader object also doesn't help

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep, it is a deadlock - try BeginInvoke()

Comment: @alexm Can you tell me more? It still won't work even when I removed the DownloadProgressChanged

Comment: `await StartDownloading();` and `private async Task StartDownloading()`

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is a deadlock. Two methods are trying to gain access to the main UI thread using the Windows message queue without giving each other a chance to continue.

Use `BeginInvoke()` instead of `Invoke()` for *posting* messages to avoid locking the UI thread in `OnDownloadProgressChanged.

like so:

```cs
private void OnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, Downloader.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
           this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
          {
               downloadProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
          }));
}
```

The code in `StartDownloading()` also has issues like using fire and forget `async void` for a long-running task. One would want to cancel it or wait until it is completed. Also it does not need to start from within the constructor, when the dialog's window is not fully constructed yet.

```cs
void StartDownloading()
{
   \\ Run download in a background thread 
   _downloadTask = Task.Run(()=>RunDownloading());
}

// Check the state of this task before closing the dialog.
Task _downloadTask;


async Task RunDownloading()
{
       var downloader = new DownloadService(downloadOpt);
       downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChanged;

       await downloader.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url1, file1);
       await downloader.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url2, file2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still does not work.No matter if I completely remove the OnDownloadProgressChanged event, it still gets stuck. Quite weird!

Comment: @Milos did you call Task.Run() like above?

Comment: yes and still nothing :( https://dotnetfiddle.net/167eZO

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a deadlock since the GUI is usable. Buttons do work. Also, how can it be a deadlock if I completely remove the progressbar updating?